# Why does a subquery return more than one row?

Tags: mysql

Where should I use GROUP BY in an update query? I want to set the count of orders in progress for each user. This is my query which returns two rows:

```
UPDATE user u 
SET u.active_orders = (
    SELECT COUNT(o.order_status) 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM user u) AS u 
    INNER JOIN goods g ON u.user_id = g.master_id 
    INNER JOIN order_details o ON g.goods_id = o.goods_id 
    WHERE o.order_status = 'IN_PROGRESS' 
    GROUP BY u.user_id);
```

Comment: The subquery isn't correlated with the main query. So it's returning all the counts, not just the count for the row that's being updated.

Comment: I think  you can safely simplify `SELECT COUNT(o.order_status) FROM (SELECT * FROM user u) AS u` to `SELECT COUNT(o.order_status) FROM  user u` Keep it simple

Answer (score 1):

The subquery needs to be correlated with the main query, so it just returns one count for each row being updated, rather than all the counts at once.

```
UPDATE user AS u1
SET u.active_orders = (
    SELECT COUNT(o.order_status) 
    FROM goods g
    INNER JOIN order_details o ON g.goods_id = o.goods_id 
    WHERE o.order_status = 'IN_PROGRESS' AND u1.user_id = g.master_id);
```

Or use a `JOIN` instead of a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE user AS u1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT g.master_id, COUNT(o.order_status) AS count
    FROM goods g
    INNER JOIN order_details o ON g.goods_id = o.goods_id 
    WHERE o.order_status = 'IN_PROGRESS' 
    GROUP BY g.master_id
) AS u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.master_id
SET u1.active_orders = IFNULL(u2.count, 0)
```

Note also that there's no need to use `users` in the subqueries, you can just use `goods.master_id` in its place.